# Building a Spring State Machine based on events and a set of criteria

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, fsm, spring-statemachine

I want to build a State Machine that may have a separate set of Events and/or States for a set of criteria (like Users, Location, etc...) There will be a base FSM and many custom FSMs for combination of the above criteria.

Eg:

User U1 has a separate FSM

User U2 = > Uses global FSM

User U3 @ Location India => Has a separate FSM

User U3 @ Location USA => Has a different FSM

All Users @ Location UK => Have a different FSM

I was looking at Spring State Machine's Regions, but looks like this can't be implemented with that.

Is there a way I can implement this using Spring State Machine or can someone suggest any other FSM Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, regions would not help here as then you'd just have parallel states.

One option is to create a statemachine which as is would be the global. Then for every other statemachine type/user you'd create a new state(this would become a parent state) on a global one and all substates on that is then handled in a substatemachine. Then on a global machine you could conditionally transition to states handling substates. Thought in spring-statemachine there is a limitation that all substates in different machines needs to have a different state id's.

I'd probably just try to build different machine configurations and then conditionally request different machines depending on a criteria.